# Memory issue with gStreamer 1.0

Tags: linux, gstreamer, file-descriptor

I have an application which uses gstreamer for audio playback.
It was written for GStreaemr0.10 version.

Recently I have modified this for GStreamer1.0. But with 1.0 the application is taking a lot of additional memory.

Later it is observed that, the process is having more unclosed file descriptors as we use the application for a long time. (The more tracks are played, the more file descriptors are open)

Is it an issue with the latest GStreamer version?
Any hint to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try with latest git version to see if it was solved? If not, you should file a bug and provide a sample application reproducing the issue. Bugs are filled at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a lot more information.